# Custom XLForm Section background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibackgroundcolor, xlform

I wish to change the BackgroundColor of a Section (or the Form) within an [XLForm](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm).

- [Change background color and tint of section](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm/issues/335)
- [Customize Section Header and Footer](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm/issues/347)

---

Section - Multi Valued Row Template.

`section.multivaluedRowTemplate.cellConfig[@"backgroundColor"] = kBackgroundColor;`

---

With a row

`row.cellConfigAtConfigure[@"backgroundColor"] = kBackgroundColor;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a reply on GitHub from @mats-claassen

- https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm/issues/335

---

*Code*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[self tableView] registerClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"headerFooterReuseIdentifier"];
}
```

**Header**

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerFooterView = [[self tableView] dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"headerFooterReuseIdentifier"];
    headerFooterView.contentView.backgroundColor = kBackgroundColor;

    return headerFooterView;
}
```

**Footer**

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerFooterView = [[self tableView] dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"headerFooterReuseIdentifier"];
    headerFooterView.contentView.backgroundColor = kBackgroundColor;

    return headerFooterView;
}
```